# how to controll a scroll on top of bottom nav bar

Tags: flutter, layout

I have write a flutter app to show a card list with bottom nav bar. but last row of card list hide in bottom nav bar. hot to resolve it or how to control my scolllist. i am new in flutter.
Thanks
[image]
as per above screen the list should scroll with bottom space so that last row of list should be visible. or suggest my any idea how to achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: just put ur scolllist .like  SafeArea( child: ListView())

Comment: already apply but not work

Comment: i am using persistent bottom nav bar

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the widget tree like this:

```
Scaffold(
  appbar: ...
  body: Column(
    children: [
      ...
      Expanded(child:ListView(...)),// This is your scrollable list
    ]
  )
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: items);//Your bottom nav bar
)
```

My Code as:

```
return SafeArea(
                child: Expanded(
                    child: GridView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                          childAspectRatio: (1.5),
                        ),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () => {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                Transmainlist(
                                                    shift: snapshot
                                                        .data![index]))),
                                  },
                                  child: Card(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        side: const BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                            8.0), //<-- SEE HERE
                                      ),
                                      color: Colors.yellow[300],
                                      elevation: 3.0,
                                      child: Container(
                                          margin:
                                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                              child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Text(
                                                snapshot
                                                    .data![index].shname!,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 15,
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                              const Divider(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                thickness: 1,
                                              ),
                                              if (1 == 1)
                                                Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceEvenly,
                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                      CrossAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    if (snapshot
                                                            .data![index]
                                                            .showresult ==
                                                        'show')
                                                      ResultView(
                                                          result: snapshot
                                                              .data![index]
                                                              .sresult
                                                              .toString()),
                                                    if (snapshot
                                                            .data![index]
                                                            .showresult ==
                                                        'show')
                                                      ResultView2(
                                                          date: snapshot
                                                              .data![index]
                                                              .rdate),
                                                    if (snapshot
                                                            .data![index]
                                                            .showresult ==
                                                        'hide')
                                                      SaleView(
                                                          sale: snapshot
                                                              .data![index]
                                                              .sale,
                                                          col: snapshot
                                                              .data![index]
                                                              .col)
                                                  ],
                                                )
                                            ],
                                          )))),
                                ),
                              ));
                        })),
              );
```